# How do you simulate a null safe operator with a default return value?

Tags: java, guava

I'm sorry for the title but I cant find a good way to describe the problem in one sentence. In short, I have a lot of Java code following this pattern

```
if (obj != null && obj.getPropertyX() != null) {
    return obj.getPropertyX();
}
return defaultProperty;
```

which can be rewritten as

```
return obj != null && obj.getPropertyX() != null ? obj.getPropertyX() : defaultProperty;
```

It's still ugly and I'm wondering if there is some API in Google Guava or other library to help clean up this code. Specifically, I'm looking for something like

```
return someAPI(obj, "getPropertyX", defaultProperty);
```

I can implement this method using reflection but I'm not sure if that's the proper way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: Other languages have a "Safe navigation operator", where you could say `obj?.getPropertyX()` instead of `obj == null ? null : obj.getPropertyX()`. For example, Groovy and C#. But Java chose to have the Optional class instead.
http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_safe_navigation_operator

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In Java 8, you could use:

```
return Optional.ofNullable(obj).map(Obj::getPropertyX).orElse(defaultProperty);
```

Comment: There's one remaining thing that makes this answer less than 100% perfect: if defaultProperty were an expression rather than a value, then in the question defaultProperty would only be evaluated when necessary, but in this answer it would be evaluated unconditionally.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou You should suggest `orElseGet`.

Comment: Thanks. This works, but not really clean as I expected :( Anyway, I didnt know about the safe navigation operator in other languages, that looks so elegant.